# SocketAsyncEventArgs vs NetworkStream vs BeginXXX methods performance?

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, methods, mmo

I'm working on a MMO game server project and I have to select a method for use sockets. I've read some articles and I've asked some questiongs in here but I can't understand this very well: some libraries uses networkStream, some applications uses beginreceive like async. methods and somebody tells me use SocketAsyncEventArgs (everyone is high-performance). Now if I prefer to use BeginReceive() methods, am I going to make a mistake (or is this choise effects performance)?

**EDIT:** What are the differences between them?

Comment: Well, the fact that the Socket `*Async` (but not `async`, if you see what I mean) methods were added most recently, specifically to target performance-centric scenarios should probably suggest that is your best bet...

Comment: @MarcGravell *Async namely ReceiveAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs), Am I wrong? EDIT: And do we know why SocketAsyncEventArgs better? I'm asking this because networkcomms (http://www.networkcomms.net/) like libraries not uses SocketAsyncEventArgs and they are high-performance.

Comment: yes that is what I meant, and: some others *do* use the *Async API. I don't have a direct comparison to hand.

Comment: @MarcGravell OK. I've started to research something about them :)